# Minimax Implementation Planet Wars Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, artificial-intelligence, minimax, minmax

I am very new to Artificial Intelligence and mostly have experience in theoretical Computer Science/AI. As a little project, I am trying to implement the minimax algorithm on a simplified version of the Google AI challenge of a few years back. Unfortunately, after a lot of trying and pseudocode reading, I have not been able to successfully implement it yet.

Planet Wars is a game between two players with their own planets. Every turn a player can decide from which of his own planets, to send half of its ships, to a neutral or opponents planet. In this way, it is possible to take over the opponent's planets. You win when the opponent has no planet left.

As of yet I have written this:

```
max_depth = 4

def minmax(pw, depth):
    max_player(pw, depth)
    return [max_source,max_dest]

def min_player(pw, depth):
    if depth > max_depth:
    return evaluate_state(pw)
    min_score = 10000

for my_planet in pw.my_planets(pw):
    for not_my_planet in pw.not_my_planets(pw):
        sim = simulate_move(pw)
        simulated_pw.SimulateAttack(my_planet, not_my_planet)
        score = max(sim, depth +1)
        if score < min_score:
            score = min_score
return min_score

def max_player(pw, depth):
    if depth > max_depth:
        return evaluate_state(pw)
    max_score = -10000
    global max_source
    global max_dest
for my_planet in pw.my_planets(pw):
    for not_my_planet in pw.not_my_planets(pw):
        sim = simulate_move(pw)
        sim.SimulateAttack(my_planet, not_my_planet)
        score = min(sim, depth +1)
        if score > max_score:
            score = max_score
            max_source = my_planet
            max_dest = not_my_planet
return max_score

def do_turn(pw):
    source = None
    destination = None

# (1) Implement an algorithm to determine the source planet to send your ships from  
source = minmax(pw, 4)[0]

# (2) Implement an algorithm to determine the destination planet to send your ships to
destination = minmax(pw, 4)[1]

# (3) Attack/Defend
# If the source and destination variables contain actual planets, then
# send half of the ships from source to destination.
if source is not None and destination is not None:
    pw.issue_order(source, destination)
```

But when trying to play against another bot, terminal gives this in return:

```
Johannas-MacBook-Pro:PlanetWars johannakorte$ python play.py -1 MinMax2.py     -2 BullyBot.py -s

Game[1]: Something went wrong, engine output dump:

-------------------------

Engine entering main game loop. Mode serial

Game state turn 0

Player 1 said: Traceback (most recent call last):

Player 1 said:   File "src/python/MinMax2.py", line 74, in <module>

Player 1 said:     main()

Player 1 said:   File "src/python/MinMax2.py", line 69, in main

Player 1 said:     do_turn(pw)

Player 1 said:   File "src/python/MinMax2.py", line 52, in do_turn

Player 1 said:     source = minmax(pw, 4)[0]

Player 1 said:   File "src/python/MinMax2.py", line 14, in minmax

Player 1 said:     max_player(pw, depth)

Player 1 said:   File "src/python/MinMax2.py", line 36, in max_player

Player 1 said:     for my_planet in pw.my_planets(pw):

Player 1 said: TypeError: my_planets() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Player 1 timeout: you missed a turn! Consider to make your bot faster, or    increase the maxTurnTime.

Game state turn 1

Game state turn 2

Couldn't write to stdin of player 1
```

It seems like my bot is missing a turn by being either not fast enough or does not make a decision.

I would appreciate any input or feedback! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code crashes because of this line: `for my_planet in pw.my_planets(pw):`.

Replacing it with `for my_planet in pw.my_planets():` will at least get rid of one error. This is because pw is a class, meaning all functions on that class automatically take `self` as a first parameter. You don't, and shouldn't, supply this first parameter!

To explain it with a simplified example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self): pass
    def show42(self):
        return 42
class1 = MyClass()

# This will work:
print(class1.show42())
# 42

# ... but this will crash
print(class1.show42(class1))
# It will crash with: TypeError: show42() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```